# java.lang.SecurityException: Requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission

Tags: android, geolocation

I am developing an android where I want to get user location using NETWORK_PROVIDER,I am not using GPS for this purpose.I am getting following exception

java.lang.SecurityException: Requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission

and I am using following code.]

```
tx=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000,
    10f, this);
    tx.setText("Status="+lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));
```

and manifest file

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The permissions are placed in the manifest tag (not in the application tag) i.e

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="package.mypackage" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.2">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Some Permissions and Enjoy with your Application Code

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```